# Backbone add class to last element in collection view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In the message view I am trying to target the last element in the collection, I can only target the model and not the el.

Below I get the console to return the el, but for some reason it does not exist in the DOM, when I try to add a class to `$(this.$el)` nothing happens. So I am stumped.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

var MessageView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    className: 'message',
    template: require('../../templates/message.hbs'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.test, this);
    },
    test: function() {
        console.log($(this.$el));

        // Would like to target that last element
        // so I can use somethng like bounce.js to
        // add an animation to the newly added message
    }


});  

module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    className: 'collection',
    initialize: function() {
        // this is triggered in a parent view with the .create method
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: MessageView

});
```

I am trying to add an animation to the newly added item, but I cannot target the last element in that view. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am just going to do it like this. Works fine. Inside my create method I will just target the `:last` item in the collection, it re renders the whole collection it appears, so each time a message is created a new list is created therefore making the newly created message the last one.

```
// send the message to the DB (client submit triggers this)
if($message.val() != '') {

    $message.val('');

    /* POST the message to the DB and add the message on the client side */
    window.App.data.messages.create(Message, {
        success: function(model) {
            self.scrollChat();
            self.reScroll();
            socket.emit('messageFromClient', Message);
            window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: (POST) new message created!');
            var bounce = new Bounce();
                bounce
                  .translate({
                    from: { x: -300, y: 0 },
                    to: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                    duration: 600,
                    stiffness: 4
                  })
                  .scale({
                    from: { x: 1, y: 1 },
                    to: { x: 0.1, y: 2.3 },
                    easing: "sway",
                    duration: 800,
                    delay: 65,
                    stiffness: 2
                  })
                  .scale({
                    from: { x: 1, y: 1},
                    to: { x: 5, y: 1 },
                    easing: "sway",
                    duration: 300,
                    delay: 30,
                  })
                  .applyTo($('.collection .message:last'));
        }
    });   

}
```